# Get JSON from NSURL in c# xamarin using NSURLSession

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin, nsurlsession

I'm having trouble with pulling json using nsurlsession in xamarin c#. I can't figure out how to work with the NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, DidFinishDownloading method converting the NSURL location to JSON. I tried 3 different solutions below, I want to access the JSON and make it NSDictionary for me to work with.

```
 public static void getApps () 
{
var config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration("com.SimpleBackgroundTransfer.BackgroundSession");
var session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, (NSUrlSessionDelegate) new NetworkDelegate(), new NSOperationQueue());
var url = NSUrl.FromString("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=25/json");
var request = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url);
var downloadTask = session.CreateDownloadTask (request);
downloadTask.Resume ();
}

public class NetworkDelegate : NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate {
    public override void DidFinishDownloading(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask, NSUrl location)
    {   
    //solution1
    FileStream file = File.OpenRead (location.Path);
    var jsonData = NSJsonSerialization.Deserialize(data, NSJsonReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error);
    //error: The name 'error' does not exist in the current context"

    //solution2
    NSData data = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Contents(location.Path);
    App app1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<App>(File.ReadAllText(location.Path));
    //output: top25.App

    //solution3
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(location.Path); 
    //error: "NewtonSoft.Json.JsonReaderException:
Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got U. Path '', line 1, position 1."
    }
}
```

Update: Worked with the code below but now I am getting the following error ( Breaks on the last line (NSDictionary) when deserializing. 
):

```
NSData data = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Contents(location.Path); 
NSString dataString = NSString.FromData(data, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
NSDictionary jsonDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NSDictionary>(File.ReadAllText(dataString));
```

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path (path + JSON that I need)".

Update: This prints the json as a .net object in the console. How to convert to nsdictionary?

```
NSData data = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Contents(location.Path);
NSString dataString = NSString.FromData(data, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataString); 
Console.WriteLine ("json {0}", json);
```

**RESOLVED:**

```
NSData data= NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Contents(location.Path);
NSError err;
NSDictionary jsonData = (NSDictionary)NSJsonSerialization.Deserialize(data, NSJsonReadingOptions.MutableContainers, out err);
```

Comment: location.Path is the path to a file containing the downloaded data, not the data itself.  Your third solution, DeserializeObject() expects a json string, not a file path.  You need to read the data into a string first, then deserialize it.  For your 1st solution, you should just create an NSError object and pass it in as the missing argument.

Comment: Thank you for your help!